# Не работает layout_gravity="right"

Tags: android, android-layout

Для третьего textview не работает layout_gravity="right". А вот для первого textview всё нормально. Для третьего только получается задать leftmargin, но для различных экранов это будет плохо.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
   >
<TextView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/tvLayout1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Антон"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:textSize="15dp">
</TextView>

    <LinearLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
   >
        <TextView
            xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:id="@+id/tvLayout2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Должность: программист"
            >
        </TextView>

<TextView
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/tvLayout3"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Оклад: 13000"
    android:layout_gravity="right"


>
</TextView>
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

Потому что последние два `TextView` находятся в контейнере `LinearLayout`.

В конкретно вашем случае, можно сделать так, код третьего `textView`

```
 <TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/tvLayout3"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Оклад: 13000"
        android:textAlignment="viewEnd" />
```

Либо использовать `RelativeLayout` или `FrameLayout` (вариантов как построить такую разметку очень много), а не `LinearLayout`, тогда ваш пример будет выглядит так

```
 <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/tvLayout2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Должность: программист" />

    <TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/tvLayout3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Оклад: 13000"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Горизонтальная гравитация не работает в горизонтальном `LinearLayout`, также как вертикальная - в вертикальном, т.к. все дочерние вьюхи распологаются друг за другом и игнорируют мешающие этому параметры.

Вам надо выбрать один из вариантов:

1. Растянуть 2 `TextView` на оставшееся место на экране через вес и назначить выравнивание текста через `gravity`
2. Поместить между 1 и 2 `TextView` пустую вьюху (например `Space`) у которой вес будет 1 - так она займёт оставшее место на экране.
3. Родительским элементом сделать `FrameLayout` - в нём `layout_gravity` будет работать без исклчений